# How to fix " TypeError: post_details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug' "

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

### I'm creating my blog with django, and trying to make posts urls in slug way, after I created the models and called it in views it showed me this error:
[TypeError at /posts/post/why-i-love-python-django/,

```
  post_details() got an unexpected keyword argument 'slug']
```

---

- My files are in these links:
- [1]: https://pastebin.com/VuiPn7Vf => posts/views.py,
- [2]: https://pastebin.com/HjTK5Ugz => posts/models.py,
- [3]: https://pastebin.com/03gn3mbK => posts/urls.py,
- [4]: https://pastebin.com/xAVc3ppe => templates/post.html,
- [5]: https://pastebin.com/AzMQPxrv => templates/base.html

I tried to change "id" in [posts/views.py line:102] and made it "slug", also edited it in [line:104]

in [posts/view.py line: 102]:

```
def post_details(request, id):
   post_list = Post.objects.active()
   post = get_object_or_404(Post, id=id)
   if post.publish > timezone.now().date() or post.draft:
        if not request.user.is_authenticated or not request.user.is_superuser:
             raise Http404

    share_string = quote_plus(post.content)

    initial_data = {
        "content_type": post.get_content_type,
        "object_id": post.id,
    }

    # post read time 
    read_time = get_read_time(post.content)
    # print(type(read_time))

    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)

   if form.is_valid():
        c_type = form.cleaned_data.get('content_type')
        content_type = ContentType.objects.get(model=c_type)
        obj_id = form.cleaned_data.get('object_id')
        content_data = form.cleaned_data.get('content')
        parent_obj = None
        try:
            parent_id = int(request.POST.get('parent_id'))
        except:
            parent_id = None
        
        if parent_id:
            parent_qs = Comment.objects.filter(id=parent_id)
            if parent_qs.exists() and parent_qs.count() == 1:
                 parent_obj = parent_qs.first()
    
        new_comment, created = Comment.objects.get_or_create(
            user = request.user,
            content_type = content_type,
            object_id = obj_id,
            content = content_data,
            parent = parent_obj,
        )
        return HttpResponseRedirect(new_comment.content_object.get_absolute_url())

     comments = post.comments # Comment.objects.filter_by_instance(post)  # without @property

     context = {
        'post': post,
        'share_string': share_string,
        'comments': comments,
        'comment_form': form,
        'read_time': read_time,
    }
    return render(request, 'post.html', context=context)
```

I expected the post slug to be created and added to the urls correctly

Comment: where is `urls.py` ? also when doing a POST request you don't send it as parameter. It should be passed to `request` object.

Comment: - main urls.py : https://pastebin.com/Wb7At91w , 
do you mean this paramater:
    form = CommentForm(request.POST or None, initial=initial_data)

Answer (score 0):

Your `post_details` function takes `request` (which all Django views should take) and `id` parameters, but in `urls.py` you are extracting parameter named `slug`. Your function should take that param instead of `id`.

Comment: I tried this and it gives this error: " NoReverseMatch at /posts/post/why-i-love-python-django/ , Reverse for 'post' with keyword arguments '{'id': 2}' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried: ['posts/post/(?P<slug>[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$'] "

Answer (score 0):

Solution: this problem solved by editing the [post.html] at line:53

```
<!-- path: {% url 'posts:post' id=post.id %} <br>  -->
```

and make it an acceptable "django comment" like : {# #} because server can't render html comments, so I edited to be like this:

```
{# path: {% url 'posts:post' id=post.id %} #}<!-- <br> -->
```